# Extend disk with diskpart or Disk Management

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, diskmanagement, diskpart

I have a Win 2008 Server that won't let me extend a disk.  I have used both the computer management and the diskpart tool and both tell me that I have less than 1MB free and can't extend.  I show that I have 100GB of Unallocated space and 81.5gb free on the drive.  When I reboot the server I can extend the drive but I need to be able to do it while the server is running.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I reboot the server and it allows me to extend the disk.  If it runs for a while then it will no longer work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the boot drive is it, you can't extend that with diskpart.

Comment: ...I managed to extend boot drive on the ESX windows2k3 guest using ExtPart.exe from Dell

Comment: No it is not the system drive.  It is a Win Server 2008 box.  The drive is a Lefthand SAN volume.  The process works fine on all of our other Win 2k8 servers.  This one is just being a pain and I wanted to see if anyone else had encountered the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Any Chance there is a page file on that disk? If so try moving it (long enough to extend it)

Comment: I have confirmed that there are is no page files on that disk.

Answer (score 1):

> It's not the boot drive is it, you can't extend that with diskpart.

You couldn't in Win2003, but on Win2008 it's fully supported. We do it all the time on our VMWare guests, and the procedure is the same as with any partition.

Apart from that, are you getting any errors in your event log regarding this?

Comment: It is not the boot drive.  It tells me that I cannot extend the disk because there is less than 1MB free.  It does not matter how much space we free up it still will not allow us to extend it until we boot the system.

Comment: and you make sure you rescan the disk either in disk management or run the rescan command in diskpart before attempting to extend the disk?

Comment: @trondh I will try this when we extend the drive next.

Comment: we did this and it did not help

Answer (score 0):

You could need to delete some files to release more free space.
to resize 2008 partition reference: http://www.extend-partition.com/resize-windows-server-2008-partition.html

Comment: We tried this and had no luck.  We had 700MB free and it still has this issue.

Comment: Having the same problem with 6% free on a >1TB disk in VMWare.